# RewriteRule without FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnersMatch

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm running into some problems with rewriting my URLs.

Recently moved to a new host where FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnersMatch is not allowed as options in my .htaccess file. Using these will give me a 500 error. Mod_rewrite is however enabled on the host.

Normally my rewriting code looks like the code below and works perfectly:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^link/(.*)$ link.php?urlkey=$1 [QSA]
```

But with removing +FollowSymLinks the rewriting doesn't work.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**EDIT**

In the Apache docs ([mod_rewrite - Appache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)) is stated that:

> To enable the rewrite engine in this context, you need to set "RewriteEngine On" and "Options FollowSymLinks" must be enabled. If your administrator has disabled override of FollowSymLinks for a user's directory, then you cannot use the rewrite engine.

There must be a way to write pretty URLs even when FollowSymLinks is off right..?

Comment: No direct way of rewriting that to `link.php?urlkey=…` without using the rewrite engine … Several possible workarounds: Name the script file `link` to begin with, get that parsed as PHP, and rely on Path Info to fetch the rest of the URL. Or use ErrorDocument 404 to set up a handler script that takes it from there. Or use FallbackResource.

Comment: Or ask the hoster, if they could enable SymLinksIfOwnersMatch at least.

Comment: SymLinksIfOwnersMatch is not allowed. Requested that, but was denied. The easiest solution I can think of is to write the url as link-urlkey instead of link/urlkey. This works fine, but is not as clean as with a slash.