# Problem with using Rewriterule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With RewriteRule I've always cleaned my URLs as following:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?urlkey=$1 [QSA]
```

My new host doesn't allow me to use Options +FollowSymLinks and therefore I cannot use the / anymore. So I've changed my RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^page-(.*)$ page.php?urlkey=$1 [QSA]
```

However, I need to redirect all my former URLs to the new version. I tried doing this using the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page-(.*)$ [R=301,L]
```

This is however not working. I've also tried to just make a Redirect in my .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/page/urlkey https://www.example.com/page-urlkey
```

This is also not working.

**EDIT**

As requested the actual code below:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^citywalk-(.*)$ citywalk.php?urlkey=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^citywalk/(.*)$ citywalk-(.*)$ [R=301,L]
```

For example the citywalk The Historical Centre has a urlkey the-historical-centre. The old url is citywalk/the-historical-centre.

To test this specific case and other technique:

```
Redirect 301 /citywalk/the-historical-centre https://example.com/citywalk-the-historical-centre
```

By visiting https://example.com/citywalk/the-historical-centre no redirecting takes place (the url stays the same in the browser) and no urlkey is found.

Comment: Does the hoster allow you to use `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` instead of `FollowSymLinks`?

Comment: Unfortunately they are both not allowed.

Comment: The `Redirect` directive matches against the URL _path_, not a full, absolute URL. Quote manual: _“The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with a slash. A relative path is not allowed.”_

Comment: I've also tried to Redirect 301 with the old path as `page/urlkey` and the new url as absolute url `https://www.domain.nl/page-urlkey`. This did not work as well.

Comment: And did you try it with a _correct_ path as well?

Comment: Please try: `RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /page-$1 [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: @CBroe with a correct path my redirect works. But for some reason with page/ it stays at page/ and doesnt redirect to page-.

Comment: @anubhava This doesn't work either. It stays at the page/ page and no redirect took place.

Comment: Are you confusing the meaning of “correct” with that of “specific”? I meant whether you actually used a path starting with a leading slash. Please show us the actual code you tried, instead of giving us only this vague verbal paraphrasing of what you did.

Comment: Also, I don’t get what motivated the switch from `page/foo` to `page-foo` here in the first place. I can’t find any specific documentation on what effect FollowSymlinks has _exactly_ in combination with mod_rewrite, but so far I am not convinced that change should make any difference in that regard to begin with. So what did you base this on, can you point to any reference or explanation?

Comment: @anubhava .htaccess works as I use it for example to rewrite my url to `page-urlkey` as shown in my post. Using FollowSymlinks gives me a 500 error. So that's not the case.

Comment: @CBroe I've updated my post with more detail and a specific case. Why I made the switch from / to - is shown in my previous question question regarding this RewriteRule without FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnersMatch (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063620/rewriterule-without-followsymlinks-or-symlinksifownersmatch)

Comment: That part from the docs you are quoting there, is about usage of the RewriteEngine and configuring it via .htaccess in general. This has nothing to do with whether your URLs are of the form `page/foo`, or `page-foo`.

Comment: Could be, but it doesn't change the fact that page/foo won't work anymore when I remove FollowSymLinks and page-foo works.